# LangChain & OpenAI, Comparing Documents

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, vector-database

I've done some embeddings which are labeled resumes(CV's), stored them into a pinecone with a cosine similarity search.

Is there a way to pass a .pdf file and create a comparison between inputted CV and labeled CV's?

I tried using QAretrival but not successfully.